# Can redux state be out of sync?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```
function Sorter({ redux_state_obj, set }) {
  const handle_click = () => {
    const new_state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(redux_state_obj))

    // update new_state based on redux_state_obj

    set(new_state)
  }

  return  <div onClick={handle_click}>button</div>
}
```

Suppose I click on the `Sorter` repeatedly extremely fast twice. Could the `redux_state_obj` be outdated in the second click, i.e. it is using the `redux_state_obj` before the first click made its update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is executed in the single thread with the use of event loop and task queue to ensure consistency and allow for asyncronous operations.

Here is a nice article about how it works and how tasks are scheduled: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/#try-it

The simplest algorithm of the task queue is this:

1. Check queue for tasks
2. If there are none -> go to step 1
3. If there is an oldest task -> dequeue it, wait for it to complete, then go to step 1

In your case, first click will schedule execution of `handle_click` function,
then it will be executed (modifying your redux state syncronously).
If you click when your function is executing (main thread is occupied), browser will just schedule a task to handle this second click and it will be completed only after the return of your function. So second call of `handle_click` will be executed with up-to-date state values.

That said, there can be asyncronous code in the redux or react libraries, that schedules state update to another task. In this case, your second `handle_click` call will occur BEFORE that scheduled state update. For example one of the known example of that in react is `setState` method: https://sentry.io/answers/forget-set-state-is-async/

But for that situation to occure, you have to click faster than browser executes your handler function, which can be an order of nanoseconds, so you need to be the fastest hand in the whole wild west or your handler must be written very poorely.